# PHP rename not working

Tags: php, directory, file-rename

Simple rename() function not working on server.

```
$val = "dir/1.txt";
$rval = "dir2/2.txt";
$test=rename($val, $rval);
if($test){
    echo "<br>Rename working";
}
else{
    echo "<br>Rename not working";
}
```

I am actually trying to move file to different directory using rename.  What could be the reason?

Comment: check your error log. it should give you a clue

Comment: This code works on my system.  But not on server.

Comment: again - check your error log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rename` returns **false** on failure. This could be for any number of reasons in your code.

- The destination directory does not exist
- The user running the process does not have the required privileges to write to the destination
- Source file  does not exist
- If you are running PHP < 5.3.1 and trying to move the file across drives in Windows this is not supported

etc...

Comment: Is it possible that this code may not work on remote server?

Comment: It possibly won't work on any system, for the reasons inquam noted in the bulletpoints. The code itself is correct but the operation cannot be done successfully.

Comment: Got it.  May be it is because I am using PHP Version 5.3.3

Comment: if you check your error log, it will tell you exactly why it failed.